# Why does IE respect label CSS width, but not Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a contact form however my label widths aren't being forced in Firefox or Chrome - IE seems to be working okay though (for once). Here's my HTML

```
 <form name="" id="" action="" method="post">

            <div id="my_form">

                <div>
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                </div>
            <div>
<form>
```

and here's my CSS

```
#my_form div label{width:200px;display:inline-block;}
```

any ideas how I can force the label width, they seem to collapse

Comment: Works in ff 4.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/fy3NC/

Comment: Looks OK and also works in Chrome with Nikita's pasted code.

Comment: @Nikita - agreed. It looks fine to me, Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
#my_form div label{width:200px; display:block; float:left;}
```

See this running (http://jsfiddle.net/jrpab/), it works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
#my_form label{width:200px;display:block; clear:left; float:left; }
#my_form input{display:block; float:left; width:auto;}
```

Comment: just first line, especially, `clear: left` helped for my markup (labels and inputs are inside fieldset - no divs)

Answer (score 1):

> After some head-scratching and research, I've found it's because
>   labels are inline elements, which according to CSS documentation
>   should ignore width styling. So, as usual, IE is doing it wrong and
>   Chrome and Firefox are doing it right.
>
> ...
>
> set its display property to something other than inline. I've found **display: inline-block** is the best for achieving what you're going for.

http://doctype.com/firefox-chrome-ignore-widths-my-labels